# how to print all elements of json with js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I need to create a card element for each row of the database. The problem in my function is that print only the first element. What i forgot? (the query works)

```
aggiornaEventi();

function aggiornaEventi() {
    fetch("../user_area/query/select_allevents.php").then(onResponse).then(onJson);
}

function onResponse(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function onJson(json) {

    console.log(json);

    if (json.length !== 0) {
        const eventi = document.getElementById("eventi"); //inserire l'id

        for (const evento of json) {

            const card = document.getElementById("eventi").innerHTML = `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${evento.titolo}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${evento.descrizione} | ${evento.data}</p>
                    <a href="${evento.link}" class="btn btn-primary">Vai</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           `;;


            eventi.appendChild(card);




        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with this, thanks to all

```
function onJson(json) {

    console.log(json);

    if (json.length !== 0) {
        const eventi = document.getElementById("eventi"); //inserire l'id

        for (const evento of json) {

            const card = document.createElement("eventi");

            card.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${evento.titolo}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${evento.descrizione} | ${evento.data}</p>
                    <a href="${evento.link}" class="btn btn-primary">Vai</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           `;

            eventi.appendChild(card);




        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not creating a new element for each card, instead reusing the same one over an over.

Try:

```js
// ...


          const card = Document.createElement();

          card.innerHTML = `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${evento.titolo}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${evento.descrizione} | ${evento.data}</p>
                    <a href="${evento.link}" class="btn btn-primary">Vai</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           `;

          eventi.appendChild(card);


// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You override the innerHTML of the card on 'evento' element. You should either use

```
const card = document.getElementById("eventi").innerHTML += `...`
```

or create a new element on every run with `Document.createElement();`